# Angular material style not applied in StackBlitz

Tags: angular, angular-material, stackblitz

I'm trying to create a StackBlitz project with angular material, I added the library (`@angular/material@12`) in the dependencies but the style is not implemented correctly. What am I missing?

*StackBlitz mentioned is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-44zbs8?file=src/app/app.component.html)*

---

> What I see:
>
> [image: screenshot]

---

> What I *expected* to see:
>
> [image]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you also need to import the angular material theme you'll use.

Try adding this to styles.css :

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Comment: I still get the same error.